# Makefile cross classes compilation

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++

I have a makefile that contains a main and 2 classes. The problem is that one class depends on the other but when I do the make it doesn't recognize the other class. This is an example of what I have in my makefile.

```
main : main.o class1.o class2.o
   g++ main.o class1.o class2.o -o main

main.o : main.cpp class1.h class2.h
   g++ -c main.cpp

class2.o : class2.cpp class2.h class1.h
   g++ -c class2.cpp

class1.o : class1.cpp class1.h class2.h
   g++ -c class1.cpp
```

When I do the make, the terminal keeps telling me that in class1 there is no such type as class2 and viceversa.

Comment: Please post the error, and which command is generating it.  It makes a HUGE difference whether it's the compilation that's failing, or the link.  However, my suspicion is that you have not `#include`d the `class1.h` file in the `class2.cpp` file, and vice versa.

Comment: *"It doesn't recognize the other class"* - Regardless of what you think *"It"* would be, that's not how C++ works. You make things known, there's no recognizing going on.

Comment: The error is "in the file included from class1.h:6.0, from main.cpp:1: class2.h:13:12: error "Class1" does not name a type". As I previously stated before, the #include of both classes is present IN the cpp and the header file (even though it's not necessary).

Comment: This happens viceversa if I change the order in the makefile.

Comment: Maybe there is no type `Class1` in global namespace (symbols are case-sensitive in C++). Instruct your compiler to write the preprocessed input to a file to see what's going on. And post a minimal testcase here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular include, my friend.

C++ **HATES** it when you include `class1.h` in `class2.h` and `class2.h` in `class1.h`.

Do what Ed Heal says, you need a forward declaration. Note: a forward declaration does not mean putting `#include "blah."` into the other's header file.

Example for a forward declaration:

Class1.h:

```
class Class2;

Class1 {
  // members and stuff
  Class2 *class2; 
}
```

Class2.h

```
#include "Class1.h"

Class2 {
  // members and stuff
  Class1 *class1;
}
```

See the difference? It's subtle, but important. The implementation should be in the `.cpp` files.

Also, make sure you have the header guards in place. Google "header guards C++". That will point you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use forward declarations or `#include` the header files in both `class1.cpp` and `class2.cpp`

Comment: I have both things in both classes obiously. In class1 i have the #include "class2.h" and viceversa.

Comment: I included them in both .cpp and .h files